# How to optimize finding specific object?

Tags: java, optimization, javafx

I am doing some project for my IT classes, and even though I have completed the task, I am wondering how could I improve my code for real life situation. We have given program:

1. Reading from a file (database with fields ID FIRSTNAME LASTNAME).
2. Creating `Person` Object.
3. Adding `Person` to `personArray`.
4. Adding `personArray` to my 
   `private ObservableList<AccountOwner> data =  FXCollections.observableArrayList();`

The logic behind this flow was following: I wanted to store an array, so that I would have a direct access to `Person`s Objects, so that I can have sort of two way data binding between `TableView`, and my objects.

Now, the important part is finding some of those objects. Let's say I want to find a `Person` object, with certain ID, so I can update some of its properties. Right now, I am doing the following:

```
    for (Person person:this.personArray) {
        if (person.getId().equals(someId)){
            person.addBirthday(someDate);
        }
    }
```

Which is fine with my small database (of 20 entries).

My question is: how can I improve this flow, so that it would be much more efficient in real life situation, when the database can compose of more than 10,000 entries? Iterating over the `personArray` and finding the right object would take more and more time. Is there any other way I can approach finding specific object in my app?

For interested ones - I use JavaFX with its Tables.

Comment: Well, you probably wouldn't want to cache 10,000 objects on your client, but page them in and out instead.  That said, when you do have a large number of objects and you need to do fast look-ups, usually a hash (Map) is the answer.

Comment: 10,000 is not a huge data to process for modern computers .

Answer (score 2):

`FXCollections` also provides observable `Map`s.

You could possibly map your `Person`s by their ID, and retrieve them, which is likely to perform much better than the iteration in your example.

That is, if the `Object` methods `equals` and `hashCode` are overridden efficiently (and correctly) in the object you use as key for your map.

You'd then use a `HashMap` to back your `ObservableMap`.

For larger repositories you could either look at specialized in-memory databases, or persisted, high performance databases, but the integration with JavaFX will require more effort.

- API [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/ObservableMap.html)
- Official tutorials on JavaFX collections [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/collections/jfxpub-collections.htm)

Comment: Thanks for your input! I will keep the question open for more answers for a little while! In mean time, could you provide some example of using Maps on FXCollections? No need for your own example, an article or documentation would be perfect

Comment: @uksz you're welcome. Adding a few links - I don't have a full-on example available at the moment.

Comment: The _values_ of a map don't necessarily need to override `equals` or `hashCode`. So a `Map<String, Person>` should work with minimal changes.

Comment: @MickMnemonic agreed, I fixed the answer.

Comment: Using a Map would only speed up the ID case but eg searching for firstname would still have the same performance "problem" (well 10_000 is not a problem for todays computers :-)

Anyways there's no built-in datastructure so you'd have to have a Map foreach and every combination (a map for id, a map for firstname, a map for lastname, a map for first and lastname).

Comment: @tomsontom there's always the possibility of compound IDs for multiple field searches, but in this case, the OP only seems to be interested in searching by ID.